# Android achieve this layout effect

Tags: android, layout

I am making a custom layout. How to achieve the illustrated effect for the blue layout?

[image]

Comment: Please include the code you have so far for the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class with this code: (add the required imports)

```
public class CurvedBar extends View
{
    Paint visiblePaint;
    Path path;

    public CurvedBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CurvedBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    public CurvedBar(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    void init()
    {
        visiblePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        visiblePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE); //Set your own color
        visiblePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
    {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(w, 0);
        path.lineTo(w, h);
        path.lineTo(0,h);
        path.lineTo(0, 0);
        path.quadTo(w/2, h/2, w, 0); //change the 2nd param to adjust the depth of the curve
        path.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(path, visiblePaint);
    }
}
```

Then use it as a custom view in your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:padding="8dp"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

        <your.example.package.CurvedBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="100dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the result:

[image]

You can tweak the color or the depth of the curve in the code. I have commented where those parameters are. You can layout your other controls on top of this view.